# MQTT QoS automated testing with aedes broker on node.js/net

Tags: node.js, mqtt, netsh

I want to test the QoS of the MQTT protocol. I use aedes as my broker.

For testing QoS 2, one of the test cases I'd have to evaluate, is to run a scenario where once a message is published by the client, the broker forwards it to the subscriber who receives the message but the [acknowledgement(tcp)](https://www.npmjs.com/package/aedes#instanceauthorizepublishclient-packet-doneerr) and/or the [pubrec(mqtt)](http://docs.oasis-open.org/mqtt/mqtt/v3.1.1/os/mqtt-v3.1.1-os.html#_Toc398718048) are not received by the broker. By running such a case, I check that the message is not received twice by the subscriber.

So my plan is, once a message is published by the client to run aedes.authorizePublish broker-side and set a sleep for a couple of seconds and in the meantime to block the IP of the subscriber on the used port(1883).

Have tried:

```
netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name="IP Block" dir=in 
protocol=TCP interface=any action=block remoteip=172.30.10.120 
localport=1883
```

So I expect that the broker will publish the message to 172.30.10.120(subscriber) and that no packets from subscriber should be received by the broker until I invert the netsh command with

```
netsh advfirewall firewall delete rule name="IP Block" remoteip=172.30.10.120.
```

This is the code that runs the aedes broker:

```
mqttBroker.authorizePublish = function (client, packet) {
    if (packet.topic === 'hello' && client.id === '01B4C') {
        let PACK = packet;
        setTimeout(function (packet) {
            mqttBroker.publish(PACK)
        }, 10000)
    }
}
```

So I expected to get packets like that: 
[Packets when I remove eth cable from subscribed client](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CZDwD.png)

But the packets from the image above are the ones I get when I simply remove the eth cable from my subscribed client and put it back in.

The packets I get from the procedure with the netsh commands are:
[Packets when I block the ip from subscribed client, only the direction to the broker](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J86My.png)

My questions are:

1. Is this a good way to test MQTT QoS like that?
2. How can I simulate this scenario in an automated way where no cables are removed, of course, and I block one way of the connection?

Thanks in advance

P.S. Beginner programmer..